# SAPUI5 dropdown list data binding

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to populate a dropdown list with names of employees fetched from success factors, but I can't get the response to display correctly. I can display the managerId and userId no problem just not the first and last name.

Here is the response:

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [{
                    "__metadata": {
                        "uri": "https://apisalesdemo8.successfactors.com:443/odata/v2/EmpJob(seqNumber=1L,startDate=datetime'2010-02-01T00:00:00',userId='spappar1')",
                        "type": "SFOData.EmpJob"
                    },
                    "userId": "spappar1",
                    "managerId": "rmaxx1",
                    "employmentNav": {
                        "__metadata": {
                            "uri": "https://apisalesdemo8.successfactors.com:443/odata/v2/EmpEmployment(personIdExternal='spappar1',userId='spappar1')",
                            "type": "SFOData.EmpEmployment"
                        },
                        "personNav": {
                            "__metadata": {
                                "uri": "https://apisalesdemo8.successfactors.com:443/odata/v2/PerPerson('spappar1')",
                                "type": "SFOData.PerPerson"
                            },
                            "personalInfoNav": {
                                "results": [{
                                    "__metadata": {
                                        "uri": "https://apisalesdemo8.successfactors.com:443/odata/v2/PerPersonal(personIdExternal='spappar1',startDate=datetime'1990-01-01T00:00:00')",
                                        "type": "SFOData.PerPersonal"
                                    },
                                    "lastName": "Pappar",
                                    "firstName": "Steve"
                                }]
                            }
```

Here is my data binding for the dropdown:

```
var employeeTemplate = new sap.ui.core.ListItem({
    text: "{employeeDropDownModel/employmentNav/personNav/personalInfoNav/results>firstName} {employeeDropDownModel/employmentNav/personNav/personalInfoNav/results>lastName}"
});
sap.ui.getCore().getElementById('employeeId').bindItems("employeeDropDownModel>/d/results", employeeTemplate);
```

Any help would be awesome, I have tried many different combinations to get the binding to work, but to no avail.

Comment: Do you use a named model `employeeDropDownModel`? In that case, your binding should be `employeeDropDownModel>/etc...` (i.e., if you use a named model, your binding should be prefixed with `namedmodel>`

Comment: I wonder why you try to access `lastName` and `firstName` of an **array**. Because the array obviously does not have that property. What might work is the following: `.....personalInfoNav/results/0/firstName. And as Qualiture said, the `>` belongs somewhere else.

Comment: Why not use the OData Model with an expand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments and suggestions guys, I tried many different ways:

```
employeeDropDownModel>/employmentNav/personNav/personalInfoNav/results/firstName
employeeDropDownModel>/employmentNav/personNav/personalInfoNav/results/0/firstName
```

Neither of thses worked and I do have **data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"** in my index.html.

So what I ended up doing was binding the model in the usual way and then just moving the first and last name up in the model to the same level as userId and managerId:

```
    $.each(
            this.employeeModel,function(index, value) { 
if (value.employmentNav.personNav.personalInfoNav.results.length > 0) {
    var firstName = value.employmentNav.personNav.personalInfoNav.results[0].firstName;
                                                var lastName = value.employmentNav.personNav.personalInfoNav.results[0].lastName;
                                                value['firstName'] = firstName;
                                                value['lastName'] = lastName;
                                            } else {
                                                value['firstName'] = '';
                                                value['lastName'] = '';
                                            }
                                        });
```

This solved my issue pretty well. I'm not sure if this is a very good solution, but it worked for me.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a jsbin of the entire UI flow. One thing that strikes me immediately from my experiences is that you are trying a complex binding and your index.html should have the following

```
**data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"**
```

If this does not fix, can you provide a jsbin example?

Thanks and Regards,
Veera

Comment: As he said, other properties work fine. So the problem doesn't seem to be the bindingSyntax setting.